# Case insensitive search in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, lowercase

The best way I've found to search for things where I specifically don't want character-case to matter is:

```
@tag = Rails.env.development? ? Category.where("LOWER(name) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:find]}%")[0] : Category.where("LOWER(name) ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:find]}%")[0]
```

I have to have the `.env` finder because I use Heroku, and I haven't cared to get PostgreSQL setup on my dev machines.  Still, isn't there something like:

```
@tag = Category.find_by_name(params[:find], case_sensitive: false)
```

Are there options that we can pass to the `find_by` helper in Rails?  This would be a nice one.

Comment: So, the next person to see this and think, 'F this guy, downvote,' please let me know why you think so.  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but people are probably downvoting because you made a snide remark at the beginning that serves no purpose to your question...

Comment: And which I removed because it was a non sequitur.

Comment: Duly noted.  But am I wrong?  `case_sensitive:`, `order:`, `unique:`?  Why not pass some options along to get more out of the `find_by` helper?

Comment: well, we can do `.uniq` after it, so that's moot, but I'm sure people could come up with some good ones

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Rails supports case-insensitive queries via [the built-in Arel library or a gem such as Squeel](http://robb.weblaws.org/2013/12/05/yes-rails-supports-case-insensitive-database-queries/).

Comment: Is arel included in rails?

Comment: Do I have to include it in the application.rb or at the top of my controller?  Like `include 'open-uri'`?

Comment: No, nothing like that is required. Just start using it. Arel is already used "under the hood" in Rails.

Answer (score 14):

> Are there options that we can pass to the find_by helper in Rails? This would be a nice one...

**No** there isn't. ([see the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/))
**Yes**, that would be a nice one.

You will probably not accept this answer because your question wasn't really a question
Which is probably why you got downvoted.

Maybe you could also lowercase the `params[:find]` (`params[:find].downcase`) and care to get PG setup on your dev machines.

```
Category.where("LOWER(name) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:find].downcase}%").first
```

In the meantime, you could extract the query in your model:

**category.rb**

```
def self.search_by_name(name)
  if Rails.env.development?
    where("LOWER(name) LIKE ?", "%#{name.downcase}%").take
  else
    where("LOWER(name) ILIKE ?", "%#{name}%").take
  end       
end
```

**controller**

```
@tag = Category.search_by_name(params[:find])
```

Comment: Well, there was a question.  You answered it... no, there isn't an options hash.  You can do the `.downcase` if the info in the database is, too, lower case.  I'm ok with downcasing everything, like I do with user emails when saved to the DB, but acronyms and initial-isms are definitely left upper case.  For tagging, I thought that was important to leave alone.  The PG is a non-issue, I was just explaining why I had the `Rails.env.development?` in there.

Comment: So, an options hash for `find_by`.  Any ideas on how we could implement that?  I checked the source file in `activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_finder_match.rb`, and can verify, there are no options.  It uses RegEx to interpret what you're looking for, but I'm not seeing the actual search functionality...

Comment: I was meaning to lowercase both the search term **and** the db values: `Category.where("LOWER(name) ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:find].downcase}%")[0]`. I was thinking "Maybe you should also..." but wrote "Maybe you could also..." to make it sound more like a suggestion.

Comment: Also, I won't suggest you to implement that on your own because you will end up monkey patching rails. Just extract the query in your model for now and open an issue on Github to see if people are willing to implement that officially in Rails.

Comment: Lastly the dynamic finders will be deprecated. You should use anymore `find_by_name(name)` but `find_by(name: name)`. That is if you're using Rails 4, of course.

Comment: Oups, sorry, I was meaning to downcase the search term for the `LIKE` query, not the `ILIKE`

Comment: yeah, i read somewhere that the `find_by` helpers are 'slightly deprecated'.  I don't see why... bleh.  thanks for the insight, though, delba!

Comment: It's deprecated because it uses metaprogramming techniques (method missigng) which requires to travel all the way up the methods chain. It is slow.

Comment: I disagree that you need to do this work. Use [Arel or Squeel](http://robb.weblaws.org/2013/12/05/yes-rails-supports-case-insensitive-database-queries/). Arel is built-in to Rails.