# Empty brackets '[]' appearing when using .where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, view, controller

I'm trying to display all Guides where title contains the word 'attack'. I do so like so:

```
def attack
  @guides = Guide.where(title: 'attack')
end
```

**Quick question** - How do I make it **non** case-sensitive and restrictive? It can contain any spelling of the word 'attack' like 'AtTaCK', and it can have more words. As long as Attack is in it somehow.

Then, to print them out in the view, I do this:

```
<% @guides.each do |guide| %>
  <%= guide.title %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good bet is to utilize Rails' [Arel SQL manager](https://github.com/rails/arel), which explicitly supports case-insensitive ActiveRecord queries:

```
t = Guide.arel_table
Guide.where(t[:title].matches('%attack'))
```

[Here's an interesting blog post](http://robb.weblaws.org/2013/12/05/yes-rails-supports-case-insensitive-database-queries/) regarding the portability of case-insensitive queries using Arel. It's worth a read to understand the implications of utilizing Arel across databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lower` function:

```
Guide.where("lower(title)='attack'")
```

As a comment: Work on your question. The title isn't terribly informative, and you drop a big chunk of code at the end that is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I've omitted some of the extra fluff. Let me try out your answer.

Comment: This answer got my items showing. But for some reason it's still only displaying the guides with a title of 'Attack'. I'd like all guides that have any variation of the word 'attack' to be shown. 

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Stuarts' answer is correct, but if you are not sure if you are saving the titles in lowercase, you can also make a [case insensitive search](http://robb.weblaws.org/2013/12/05/yes-rails-supports-case-insensitive-database-queries/)

There are a lot of answered questions in Stack Overflow with more data on this:

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220423/case-insensitive-search-in-rails-model)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303637/case-insensitive-search-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

For case insensitive and anywhere in title, do...

```
@guides = Guide.where("title LIKE %attack%")
```